# Update Statement assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written this query to get new values

```
select
    ol.ordernumber, 
    sum(ol.Quantity * ol.each * ol.OriginalPrice) + s.ShippingCost as New Cost
from 
    orderlines ol, orders o, ShippingMethods s
where 
    ol.ordernumber = o.OrderNumber
    and o.ShippingMethod = s.ShippingMethod
    and CreateDate between '2015-05-01' and '2015-05-31'
group by 
    ol.OrderNumber, s.ShippingCost
```

I want to update with a statement like

```
update Orders
set TotalRedoCostIncludingShipping = NewCost
```

I am just not sure how to link the two queries together to update the orders table by order number.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  And, learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2008r2

Comment: I  would encourage you to derive the data every time you need it, rather than store it.

Comment: This is the case, except we have incorrect data in the table that I need to now replace with the correct values

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
update o
set TotalRedoCostIncludingShipping = (
  select sum(ol.Quantity * ol.each * ol.OriginalPrice) + s.ShippingCost
  from orderlines ol, ShippingMethods s
  where ol.ordernumber = o.OrderNumber
  and o.ShippingMethod = s.ShippingMethod
  and CreateDate between '2015-05-01' and '2015-05-31'
  Group by s.ShippingCost
)
from Orders o
```

Regards, Damon

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```sql
with cte as 
(
  select o.OrderNumber, sum(ol.Quantity * ol.each * ol.OriginalPrice) + s.ShippingCost newcost
    from orderlines ol join orders o
      on ol.ordernumber = o.OrderNumber join ShippingMethods s
      on o.ShippingMethod = s.ShippingMethod
   where CreateDate between '2015-05-01' and '2015-05-31'
   group by ol.OrderNumber, s.ShippingCost    
)
update o
   set o.TotalRedoCostIncludingShipping = c.newcost
  from cte c join orders o
    on c.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
```